# How to obtain the date/period selected in dashboard

Tags: plugins, widget, dashboard, matomo

I am developing a custom widget plugin for Piwik. Everything works just fine. I can receive the data from a custom dimension through:

`$api->getCustomDimension(idDimension:2, idSite:1, period:'year', date:'2017-01-01');`

How can I get the user-selected date and period in the dashboard to pass it to the `getCustomDimension()` method?

As a secondary question: Is it possible to get just all data available in the database for the specified custom dimension?

[Dashboard date selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awGRB.png)